# How to use Glade to prepare ListBoxRow templates that can be created and filled programatically at runtime?

Tags: gtk, glade

I want to use a `ListBox` and dynamically add rows to it. I want to have several types of rows, each with its own components and layout, and at runtime, when I need to add a row, I want to take one of these row templates, create a new `ListBoxRow` from it, fill in the data where data needs to be filled, and add it to the `ListBox`.

I can do it manually in the code, but I want to use Glade to design these rows. The problems are that:

1. Glade only lets me add `ListBoxRow`s inside a `ListBox`.
2. These rows will be part of the `ListBox`, not external rows I can clone.
3. I don't see a GTK function for "cloning" a widget hierarchy, so I can't make these rows as actual widgets and then clone them.

Googling for an answer leads me to [things like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470680/how-do-i-set-a-liststore-model-on-pre-created-listbox-from-glade), that fixate on `TreeView` and setting a model for it, but I need a `ListBox` because I need freely customizable rows.

I thought about extracting the row node into separate XML, and each time use a new builder to re-create a new row from that new XML and fill in the data. This works, but feels hacky and can't be too performent - there has to be a better way!

Is there an official way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is actually multi-faceted, so here goes.

1. It is possible to have a `ListBoxRow` outside of a `Listbox` by adding a row and then drag-and-dropping it outside the `ListBox`. This way you can add the row (to be shown later) to the `Listbox` using something like:

   `listbox = self.builder.get_object("listbox")
   row = self.builder.get_object("row")
   listbox.insert(row, 0)`

2.It is not possible to clone or duplicate Glade widgets. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584193/clone-a-gtkwidget-from-glade-so-it-will-be-reusable-several-times-in-application) for more details.

3.You might want to think about generating your widgets and `ListBoxRow`s in code, if they happen to be fairly static. This won't work well for widgets that are getting updated in the Glade file on a regular basis.